# A problem with a LEFT JOIN in BigQuery with a view I made

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so I have two tables: tb_orders_items and order_item_snapshot_clean.
First ill show the query:

```
SELECT min(margin1.created) as CreationDate, max(margin1.margin) as Margin, min(margin1.VoucherID) as Voucher_ID, min(margin1.Price) as Price
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM `grouponi_groupon.tb_orders_items` OrderItem
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT cast (created as date) as created, order_item_cda_margin_percentage as margin, order_item_voucher_id as VoucherID, order_item_amount as Price
FROM `grouponi_groupon.order_item_snapshot_clean` as MarginTable
)  as MarginTable on MarginTable.VoucherID = OrderItem.voucher_id
) as margin1
WHERE cast(margin1.created as DATE) >= '2021-01-01'
```

I kept this query as a view named Min_Order_Margin

In my full query I use the OrderItem table and then LEFT JOIN it with the Min_Order_Margin view using Order_Item.voucher_id = margin1.Voucher_ID

But I get NULL on my margin although when I run the view I created seperately I get a number.
The Voucher ID I use exists in both tables/view.

I feel like maybe it has something to do with the min / max additions but I cant figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try below? You seems to want aggregations by `Voucher_ID` in your *view*, I guess.

```sql
SELECT min(margin1.created) as CreationDate,
       max(margin1.margin) as Margin,
       Voucher_ID,
       min(margin1.Price) as Price
  FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM `grouponi_groupon.tb_orders_items` OrderItem
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT cast (created as date) as created, order_item_cda_margin_percentage as margin, order_item_voucher_id as VoucherID, order_item_amount as Price
          FROM `grouponi_groupon.order_item_snapshot_clean`
      ) AS MarginTable
        ON MarginTable.VoucherID = OrderItem.voucher_id
  ) AS margin1
 WHERE CAST(margin1.created as DATE) >= '2021-01-01'
 GROUP BY Voucher_ID
```

Comment: Yes Jaytiger this is eaxactly what I did eventually haha. Thank you!